# preg_replace simple text while using array data

Tags: php, preg-replace

Let's just say I have a simple text:

> testing testing testing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzfAdmAtYIY
>   more testing and random text
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZQ_RDb0lcE more text etc

And I also have simple array:

```
$arr = array('Samsung Mobile USA - El Plato Supreme', 'SET FIRE | DUBSTEP');
```

How to achieve this:

> testing testing testing pzfAdmAtYIY Samsung Mobile USA - El Plato
>   Supreme more testing and random text UZQ_RDb0lcE SET FIRE | DUBSTEP
>   more text etc

My attempt:

```
$count = 0;
$text = 'testing testing testing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzfAdmAtYIY more testing and random text http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZQ_RDb0lcE more text etc';
$arr = array('Samsung Mobile USA - El Plato Supreme', 'SET FIRE | DUBSTEP');
$string = preg_replace('/http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/ms', ' \\1 '. $arr[$count++].'', $text);
print $string;
```

Unforunately the result:

> testing testing testing pzfAdmAtYIY Samsung Mobile USA - El Plato
>   Supreme more testing and random text UZQ_RDb0lcE Samsung Mobile USA -
>   El Plato Supreme more text etc

Any help would be great.

Comment: You are looking for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), which can harbor some replacement logic such as inserting associated content from your array.

Comment: @mario, I tried 'preg_replace_callback' before but I couldn't pass my array to it. Just kept getting Fatal Error: Undefined variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = 'testing testing testing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzfAdmAtYIY more testing and random text http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZQ_RDb0lcE more text etc';

// either like this:
// $arr = array('Samsung Mobile USA - El Plato Supreme', 'SET FIRE | DUBSTEP');
// or via $GLOBALS array
$GLOBALS['arr'] = array('Samsung Mobile USA - El Plato Supreme', 'SET FIRE | DUBSTEP');


$str = preg_replace_callback('/http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/ms', function($match) {
    // this is called for each match of the expression

    // sets a counter
    static $count = 0;        

    // making $arr a global variable
    // global $arr;

    // the return value
    // $r = $arr[$count];
    // or in case it is in the $GLOBALS
    $r = $GLOBALS['arr'][$count];
    // increase the counter
    $count++;
    // and return
    return $r;
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: Any chance to take $arr from outside?

Comment: Sorry my bad for that error. Works great, but I would like to take $arr from outside function. Any chance?

Comment: What if "global" disabled by server config?

Comment: @Randy Are you talking about register_globals? That doesn't disable all globals, it just disables the setting of global variables from request parameters. $GLOBALS[variablename] or global + variablename should work.

Comment: You could also take the closure (anonymous function, whatever) out and define a function, passing the $arr by reference. Couldn't you?

Comment: @keyboardSmasher isn't it $GLOBALS not $_GLOBALS?

Comment: Nice solution, I'll give you the +1, since no one else has.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher that's PHP they have no consistent naming concept. Mixing uppercase, underline. Frustrating

Comment: That GLOBALS trick doesn't work for me either. Just keep throwing  "Notice: Undefined variable: arr".

Comment: Well, that explains it. :P

Comment: @axel.michel, super! It works great even on my server. Thank you so much!! Unfortunately, I still can't +1 it, but this solution is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace() : second parameter must be the replacement array because your example follows this rule : "If this parameter is a string and the pattern parameter is an array, all patterns will be replaced by that string".

Also mind the dots in your regex : they have to be escaped.

Result : $string = preg_replace('regex', $arr, $text);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Hmm, I just got this: 
"testing testing testing pzfAdmAtYIY Array more testing and random text UZQ_RDb0lcE Array more text etc"